# C# network programming

Tags: c#, networking

Please tell me good tutorial for learning .net network programming

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type of project you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't see why this is down-voted. Usually when it comes to network programming, this is how the question is asked, and I would expect this to be a good result for searches.

Answer (score 8):

There is a similar question that already exists with relevant answer for you: [C# Networking API’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745028/c-networking-apis).

Please take a look there. Note the options proposed in answers:

- [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)
- [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx) and [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) (I recommend looking at [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx))

Have a look at this sample for an idea of how to get `TcpClient` working: [Tcp Client Sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/TcpClientSample.htm).

**And here's a tutorial**: [C# Tutorial - Simple Threaded TCP Server](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)

Comment: please i'm looking for the same thing, but my application will be a client-server application on LAN (20 PCs max...), my problem is that i think that Sockets are too basic as technology and WCF is too evaluated ! is there somethg between the two !?

Answer (score 3):

[**C# Networking working code examples**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/CatalogNetwork.htm) 
and 
**C# Network Programming 
 by Richard Blum**.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorite. To the point and easy to grasp.
 http://www.webtropy.com/.

Answer (score 0):

On [Codeplanet](http://www.codeplanet.eu/tutorials/csharp/4-tcp-ip-socket-programmierung-in-csharp.html) there is a really nice and precise tutorials with many much-used examples. I also was about to learn about the confusing world of the network programming and this tutorial really helped me.
Otherwise you may choose the "official" tutorial on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979208.aspx).